# Collecting dependencies under sbt 0.10 (putting all dependency jars to target/scala-version/lib/)

Tags: scala, sbt

I'm using sbt 0.10 with Scala 2.9.1.

I've read
http://groups.google.com/group/simple-build-tool/browse_thread/thread/792e5360877e78/987b6af687b8e33b?lnk=gst&q=collect+jars#987b6af687b8e33b

However I don't want a one huge jar. I just want dependency jars
ending up in target/scala-2.9.1.final/lib directory.

The reason why I don't want a one huge jar, that project uses a lot of
libs, and usually only the application .jar changes. However as this
is multi-language project and not all team members have scala or sbt,
jars are just commited to git. Having one huge dar updated regullary
would inflate repo size.

How can I copy those dependencies? ;)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You didn't specify the ivy configuration to copy the configurations from but here's a fully working example that will copy *all* your managed dependencies to the `target/<scala version>/lib` folder (scala version is given by the crossTarget task). Just copy this and put it in the file `project/Build.scala` (or whatever filename you want) :

```scala
import sbt._
import Keys._

object MyBuild extends Build {

  lazy val copyDependencies = TaskKey[Unit]("copy-dependencies")

  def copyDepTask = copyDependencies <<= (update, crossTarget, scalaVersion) map {
    (updateReport, out, scalaVer) =>
    updateReport.allFiles foreach { srcPath =>
      val destPath = out / "lib" / srcPath.getName
      IO.copyFile(srcPath, destPath, preserveLastModified=true)
    }
  }

  lazy val root = Project(
    "root",
    file("."),
    settings = Defaults.defaultSettings ++ Seq(
      copyDepTask
    )
  )
}
```

If you want a specific configuration, replace

`updateReport.allFiles` by `updateReport.select(configuration = Set("compile"))` or whatever ivy configuration you want.

Answer (score 1):

The various "Classpath" keys contain different views onto the classpath, but probably the easiest thing is to modify the sbt-assembly plugin to simply drop the jars into a directory instead of doing the unzip/rezip cycle.  The plugin is very small (only 150 lines) and it's pretty obvious from a cursory glance what the right place to change is.

Answer (score 1):

See task xitrum-package:
https://github.com/ngocdaothanh/xitrum/blob/master/plugin/src/main/scala/XitrumPlugin.scala

It copies all dependencies to directory target/xitrum_package.